# Download a web page with js animated images locally for offline rendering

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, download

I want to download a webpage locally with images animated by js so I can render the exact same content offline on my computer. The image/js resources are hosted on external CDN URLs and so far I cannot achieve full success. The URL is

https://matterport.com/discover/space/BTQ8RmvwnXo

Could it be done?

So far I have tried different curl/wget options and the Save As option of the browser, but I cannot replicate the same content this way.